# The application has stopped unexpectedly!

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two class as trial.java and ImageWoLab0.java(Image without lable 0).When I run my application I am getting error as : **The application has stopped unexpectedly**!!

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    switch (v.getId()) 
    {
    case R.id.btnSequence:
        Intent intent1 = new Intent();
        intent1.setClass(this,ImageWoLab0.class);       /*To open new Screen/Activity */
        //intent1.putExtra("String_key", "value");  /*Passing a key/value(Condition) to Activity2.class*/
        startActivity(intent1);                     /*open the new screen/Activity*/
        break;

    case R.id.btnVideo:
        Intent intent2 = new Intent();
        intent2.setClass(this,Activity2.class);
        intent2.putExtra("String_key", "value1");
        startActivity(intent2);
        break;

    case R.id.btnInfo:
        Intent intent3 = new Intent();
        intent3.setClass(this,Activity2.class);

        intent3.putExtra("String_key", "value2");
        startActivity(intent3);
        break;
    }
```

othar class as:

```
public class ImageWoLab0 extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

{
    private static String TAG = "tag";

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    Log.i(TAG, "abc");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image0);
    ImageButton o1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);
    o1.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    switch (v.getId()) 
    {
    case R.id.next:
        Intent intent1 = new Intent();
        intent1.setClass(this,ImageWoLab1.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
        break;


    }

}
```

}

I have clean again and again even rebuild again still the same messageis displaying. I am getting log as:sorry if I have not send log in right format(first time i am using logcat):

```
11-08 12:48:55.084: INFO/tag(334): abc
11-08 12:48:55.154: WARN/dalvikvm(334): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-08 12:48:55.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 12:48:55.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.Trial/com.example.Trial.ImageWoLab0}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
11-08 12:48:55.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-08 12:48:55.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-08 12:48:55.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-08 12:48:55.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-08 12:48:55.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 12:48:55.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-08 12:48:55.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-08 12:48:55.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 12:48:55.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-08 12:48:55.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-08 12:48:55.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-08 12:48:55.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 12:48:55.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
11-08 12:48:55.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at com.example.Trial.ImageWoLab0.onCreate(ImageWoLab0.java:21)
11-08 12:48:55.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-08 12:48:55.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-08 12:48:55.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     ... 11 more
11-08 12:48:55.264: WARN/ActivityManager(61):   Force finishing activity com.example.Trial/.ImageWoLab0
11-08 12:48:55.274: WARN/ActivityManager(61):   Force finishing activity com.example.Trial/.Trial
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks Yuliy!!i have resolved the problem, Actually in xml i was taking imageview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

while on .java file i was making object of imagebutton as:

`ImageButton o1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);

    o1.setOnClickListener(this);` 
now problem solved!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on that log, you're getting a ClassCastException in onCreate. There's only one line where you do any casting. Are you sure that the thing with ID `name` is actually an ImageButton and not something else?

Comment: i have recheck my image,class,manifest etc everything fine here!!please help me if you want i can send some code also.i want to tell one more thing that recently i have deleted one class file and all the references of that class also for example activity entry in manifest,.xml etc.I dont think this deletion is causing problem!!!