# Dice Emulation - ImageView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, imageview

I am trying to emulate dice using ImageView.  When I click the button, nothing seems to happen.  I have hard coded this example to replace the image with imageView4 for debugging purposes (I was making sure the random wasn't fail).  Now the application is crashing when I run it on a 2.2 vanilla emulator. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?  I am new to Java, Eclipse and Android so I'm sure I've probably made more than one mistake.

**Java:**

```
package mobile.applications.yahztee4;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Yahtzee4Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    ImageButton dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5;
    Button roll, begin;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);              

        PlayGame();

    }

    public void PlayGame()  
    {  
        dice1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btndice1);  

        begin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnroll);
        roll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnbegin);

        begin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Random rand = new Random();     
                int rndInt = rand.nextInt(6) + 1; // Random number between 1 and 6

                String imgName = "die" + rndInt;

                int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());  
                dice1.setImageResource(id);                 
            }
        });  
    }  
}
```

**XML for the button:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.13" >


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1&apos;s" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="3 of Kind" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="2&apos;s" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="4 of Kind" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="3&apos;s" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Full House" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="4&apos;s" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Sm Straight" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </TableRow>


         <TableRow
             android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView17"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="5&apos;s" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView18"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="TextView" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView19"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="Lg Straight" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView20"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="TextView" />
         </TableRow>

         <TableRow
             android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView21"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="6&apos;s" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView22"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="TextView" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView23"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="Yahtzee" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView24"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="TextView" />
         </TableRow>

         <TableRow
             android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView25"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="Bonus (35)" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView26"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="TextView" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView27"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="Chance" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView28"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="TextView" />
         </TableRow>

         <TableRow
             android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView29"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="Upper Score" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView30"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="TextView" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView31"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="Lower Score" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView32"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="TextView" />
         </TableRow>

         <TableRow
             android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView33"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="Yz Bonus" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView34"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="TextView" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView35"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="Total Score" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView36"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="TextView" />
         </TableRow>

         <TableRow
             android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView37"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="Turn#" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView38"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="TextView" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView39"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="Total Score" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView40"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="Roll #" />
         </TableRow>

         <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/tableRow11"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center" >

              <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/btndice1"
                  android:layout_width="60dip"
                  android:layout_height="70dip"
                  android:padding="2dip" />              
              <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/btndice2"
                  android:layout_width="60dip"
                  android:layout_height="70dip"
                  android:padding="2dip" />

              <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/btndice3"
                  android:layout_width="60dip"
                  android:layout_height="70dip"
                  android:padding="2dip" />

              <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/btndice4"
                  android:layout_width="60dip"
                  android:layout_height="70dip"
                  android:padding="2dip" />

              <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/btndice5"
                  android:layout_width="60dip"
                  android:layout_height="70dip"
                  android:padding="2dip" />

        </TableRow>

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btnroll"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/roll" 
          />

          <Spinner
              android:id="@+id/spinner"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:prompt="@string/score_prompt_spinner" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btnbegin"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/begin" />

    </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**Error Log File**

```
06-10 18:21:31.674: D/AndroidRuntime(705): Shutting down VM
06-10 18:21:31.674: W/dalvikvm(705): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-10 18:21:31.684: E/AndroidRuntime(705): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 18:21:31.684: E/AndroidRuntime(705): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{michelle.harris.yahztee4/michelle.harris.yahztee4.Yahtzee4Activity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
06-10 18:21:31.684: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
06-10 18:21:31.684: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-10 18:21:31.684: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-10 18:21:31.684: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-10 18:21:31.684: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-10 18:21:31.684: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-10 18:21:31.684: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-10 18:21:31.684: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 18:21:31.684: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-10 18:21:31.684: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-10 18:21:31.684: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-10 18:21:31.684: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 18:21:31.684: E/AndroidRuntime(705): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
06-10 18:21:31.684: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at michelle.harris.yahztee4.Yahtzee4Activity.PlayGame(Yahtzee4Activity.java:28)
06-10 18:21:31.684: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at michelle.harris.yahztee4.Yahtzee4Activity.onCreate(Yahtzee4Activity.java:22)
06-10 18:21:31.684: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-10 18:21:31.684: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-10 18:21:31.684: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing nothing to the view itself. You are currently creating a new ImageView object, and assign the drawable to it, but you're not displaying it anywhere.
Either in onCreate get your ImageView by findViewById(..) or in the onMyButtonClick you should be able to cast the View you're getting as parameter to ImageView and then change the drawable / resource depending on your "rndInt".

Comment: Thank you for the help, I tried to fix it and now the app is crashing.

Comment: Well that does not help me in any way. What exactly did you do? What's the error trace saying? Just check in which line the error occurs and read what kind of exception it's throwing, that helps in most cases.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize hitting enter would submit the comment.  I posted the error log with the new code that I have.  I suspect that it is something to do with the "android.widget.ImageView" exception.  I saw this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121957/the-application-has-stopped-unexpectedly but the btndice1 is an image button so I am not sure what the issue is.

Comment: dice1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btndice1);  but in the XML, the id btndice1 is an ImageView. <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/btndice1"
                  android:layout_width="60dip"
                  android:layout_height="70dip"
                  android:padding="2dip" /> - either change it to imagebutton OR imageview. not "both".+